# In Windows driver - app connection, app main() break with error

Tags: windows, connection, driver

```
       #define IOCTL_TEST CTL_CODE(FILE_DEVICE_UNKNOWN, 0x801, METHOD_BUFFERED, FILE_ANY_ACCESS)
...
     NTSTATUS MyIOControl(IN PDEVICE_OBJECT DeviceObject, IN PIRP Irp){
            PIO_STACK_LOCATION pStack;
            NTSTATUS returnStatus = STATUS_SUCCESS;
            ULONG ControlCode;
            pStack = IoGetCurrentIrpStackLocation(Irp);
            ControlCode = pStack->Parameters.DeviceIoControl.IoControlCode;
            switch (ControlCode)
            {
            case IOCTL_TEST:
                DbgPrint("IOCTL_TEST SJ~");
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
            Irp->IoStatus.Status = STATUS_SUCCESS;
            IoCompleteRequest(Irp, IO_NO_INCREMENT);
            return returnStatus;
        }
```

This is driver code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
#define IOCTL_TEST CTL_CODE(FILE_DEVICE_UNKNOWN, 0x801, METHOD_BUFFERED, FILE_ANY_ACCESS)
void main(){
    HANDLE dHandle;
    WCHAR DeviceLink[] = L"\\\\.\\sjdriver";
    DWORD dwRet;
    dHandle = CreateFileW(DeviceLink, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    if (dHandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){
        printf("Get Device handle Fail : 0x%X\n", GetLastError());
        _getch();
        return;
    }

    if (!DeviceIoControl(dHandle, IOCTL_TEST, 0, 0, 0, 0, &dwRet, 0)){
        printf("DeviceIOControl Fail \n");
        _getch();
        CloseHandle(dHandle);
        return;
    }
    CloseHandle(dHandle);
}
```

This is app code.
When i execute app, Windbg print "IOCTL_TEST SJ~" string well. But after print, system break with error and break point hang on app main() function's last line.  I develop this with visual studio 2013. 
Do I miss something exception process?  Why app's break occure and system fall in freezing?

Comment: Since the system is failing when you close the handle, perhaps the problem is in your DispatchClose routine?  What error code/message is being generated?

Comment: *** Fatal System Error: 0x0000003b
                       (0x00000000C0000005,0xFFFFF8800174F4D3,0xFFFFF88004B98ED0,0x0000000000000000)  But if i put print() before HANDLE dHandle;, this print() not printed and system freezing is occure first(?).  Is it some sign?

Comment: I remove CloseHandle(), but same...

Comment: I add while(true){scanf("%d", &num);} to last line of app, then system down NOT occure.  When i close application, system down occure.  What i have to do more?

Comment: Plus, i find that if CloseHandle() of app called, IRP_MJ_CLEANUP of driver called not IRP_MJ_CLOSE.

Comment: Might be an issue in DispatchCleanup then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

STOP error 0x3B is [SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff558949%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> The SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION bug check has a value of 0x0000003B. This indicates that an exception happened while executing a routine that transitions from non-privileged code to privileged code.

This suggests that the exception is not taking place inside your driver's own code (since that is kernel mode) but within the Windows executive.

The exception in question is 0xC0000005, [STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff546823%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> An access violation is an attempt to perform an operation on a page that is not permitted under the current page protection settings.

The error is occurring when the handle is closed, either because you close it explicitly or as a result of the process exiting.  Putting all that together, it seems likely that you are corrupting some critical Windows object, perhaps the device object or the IRP.

You may be able to get additional clues by analysing the crash dump with Windbg, in particular the [exception context record](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff562945%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) may contain useful information.

Comment: Is not code problem?  Actually i think CloseHandle() have problem.  When i add while(true)..., i remove CloseHandle().  I add CloseHandle() again before while(true)~ this down too.

Comment: There's a problem with the code in the device driver.  I don't think it's in the part of the code you posted, that looks OK to me.

Comment: I use NDIS LWF sample code... and add app - driver connection part only in driverentry, driverunload...

Comment: The bug has to be somewhere in the driver code, or perhaps in the way you're building, installing, or debugging it.  There's no way for a bug in an application to crash the operating system.  Does the problem occur if you use the *unmodified* sample code?

Comment: There is no app - driver connection part in unmodified sample code.  If i remove app - driver connection part in my code or not execute app for driver connection,  ONLY driver execution, unload, install and delete is not problem.

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand your English.  What exactly do you mean by "driver connection part" (the DispatchCreate routine?) and what are you trying to tell me about it?